# Localization of external data and scalability

Tags: android, database

When a user finishes a workout in my app the workout is stored on their device with the name of the exercise together with an ID and some other fields.

Now that Im localizing the app Ive run into the problem that Ill have to "manually" translate the exercise names to the localized language. This brings up the question of scalability. When my app is available in many more languages Id like a system which is lightweight and so that minimal amount of work has to be done to translate exercises.

**My most robust idea this far is:**

Using the ID of each exercise to set its data when loading it. Name, instructions and all other fields will then be loaded in the localized language upon launch. The database will update itself when it detects that a new language is available. This system could be used throughout the app to translate schedules and all other data containing exercises as well. This system is also good when downloading images for the exercises from my future server.

Now on paper this seems very good. But I dont want to implement it without asking here since I didnt find any good resources on how to implement such a thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally you would use the res/values/string.xml to contain all the strings in your app. Then to translate you only need to copy the string.xml to another values folder reflecting the language. This also has the advantage that your app by default will be loaded in the default language of the device, if available in your app. Maybe I misunderstood external as being a database on the device, but well ill leave the comment just in case.

Comment: @cYrixmorten Yes, I have done this and I have over 2000 lines of strings formatted as JSON in different values-language folders. The problem is that the users have english strings on their device which I would like to update to the specific languages.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question again, my understanding is that you store the actual String of the exercise name. Why not just store the int pointing to a string.xml value, like for instance R.string.situps. This way it is independent of language and, when reloaded, the correct language will be chosen.

Perhaps this is what you mean with ID?

In that case I believe that to be a good idea :)

Comment: I have two versions of the app and doesnt the XML identifier change? Either way this solution would leave me with crazy IDs with a lot of numbers instead of a simple list from 0 to the number of exercises. I would then have to adapt my server to follow this crazy ID for all pictures too and then it would just be simpler to have database coupled to the IDs. No?

Comment: True, thinking about it I think you might be right. Yes, I believe a relational database would make perfect sense and then make the exercise entry point to the ID of the right translation.

Comment: Might be a difficult setup but cannot help but to consider reusing the string.xml files from the project. Somehow making the server able to parse those to get the correct translation. That way you only had to do translation one place but I have no idea of how extensive an operation that would be, just a thought.